# Mysql convert varchar to date php

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a field in my database that stores a date as a VARCHAR that looks like this:

```
      2014-10-09T07:10:46
```

I'm trying to convert that into a date and display it as %Y-%M by doing the following;

```
      'Month' => array(
        'chart' => 'line',
        'fields' => array(
        array(
         'field' => 'date_format(str_to_date(cd.field_closed_date_value,\'%Y-%M-%dT%H:%i:%S\'), \'%Y-%m\')',
         'alias' => 'month',
         'label' => 'Month',
         'type' => 'string',
         'sort' => 'ASC',
        ),
       ),
      ),
```

The original code that worked was like this:

```
'Day' => array(
'chart' => 'line',
'fields' => array(
  array(
    'field' => 'date_format(from_unixtime(n.created), \'%Y-%m-%d\')',
    'alias' => 'day',
    'label' => 'Day',
    'type' => 'string',
    'sort' => 'ASC',
  ),
),
),
```

But that code uses the created date and I'm needing to use the closed date, which isn't in the same format. I know I've probably got this really wrong, I'm trying to work with what was here when I took on this project, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you storing the date as a string in varchar? (without even storing the timezone, also) The best way to store dates is either as timestamps in an integer column or as dates in a datetime column... (I personally prefer/recommend the first option)

Comment: I completely agree, I'm not sure why its stored like this, but I have to do this without modifying the current database.

Comment: @Qualcuno Maybe its all UTC and therefore no timezone?

Comment: @dognose timezone aside, storing dates as strings is a waste of space and makes it harder to do operations on them

Comment: This field is in Drupal btw and is of type Date(ISO) which I guess is just stored as a VARCHAR by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `date()` and the `strtotime()` function like this:

```
date("Y-M",strtotime('2014-10-09T07:10:46')) // returns "2014-Oct"
```

`strtotime()` accepts ISO date format and returns a UNIX timestamp, `date()` can then convert the timestamp into a custom format.